# executing code which reads from file and outputs data

Tags: java, arrays

My code is meant to read from a random file that looks like this: (but without blank lines in between)

Amy 12.23 7.43 4

Jake 9.01 23.34 3

Alan 34.00 34.21 7

The file will always have this format but could be any number of lines. I made up a .txt document that looked like this to test my code. When I tried to run it on command line nothing happened. Any suggestions why and what I can do to fix that?

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
 import java.io.*;
   public class EmployeePay {
     public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException  {
        if (args.length != 1) {  
         final String msg = "Usage: EmployeePay name_of_input file";
          System.err.println(msg);
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(msg);
           }
       int linesCount = 0;
       final String inputFileName = args[0];
       final File input = new File (inputFileName); 
       final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileReader(input));

      while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
      linesCount = linesCount +1; 
      }
      String identification[] = new String[linesCount];
      double workTime [] = new double [linesCount];
      double moneyPerHour [] = new double [linesCount];
      int totalDeductions [] = new int [linesCount];
        for(int i = 0; i < linesCount; i++){
         String line = scanner.nextLine();
         String [] lineParts = line.split(" ");
         identification[i]= lineParts[0];
         workTime[i]= Double.valueOf(lineParts[1]);
         moneyPerHour[i] = Double.valueOf(lineParts[2]);
         totalDeductions[i] = Integer.parseInt(lineParts[3]);
          double totalGrossPay = 0.00;
            if ((workTime[i] >= 1.0) && (moneyPerHour[i] >= 15) &&   (totalDeductions[i]>0)&&(totalDeductions[i]<35)){
             double totalPay[] = new double[linesCount];
             totalPay[i] = workTime[i] *moneyPerHour[i];
             totalGrossPay += totalPay[i];

             double theTaxRate = 0.15;
             double taxTotal = theTaxRate * totalGrossPay; 

            double max = Double.MIN_VALUE;
            for (int a =0; a< linesCount; a++) { 
             if (totalPay[a] > max) { 
               max = totalPay[a]; 
            }
          }
        System.out.println(totalGrossPay);
        System.out.println(taxTotal);
        System.out.println(max);

    }

   }
 }
 }
```

Comment: Formatting is awful. Not the answer to your logic problem, I know. It looks like you are using scanner two times, the second time in the loop you've already scanned past the end of the file.

Comment: Look at your **while** loop. How do you expect it too read the data in file. Properly indent your code so that it's at least somewhat readable. Use of a debugger would be handy here so that you can step through the code to see what is happening.